# Get the source code of FP Growth algorithm used in WEKA to see how it is implemented

Tags: weka, data-mining

I am currently working on a project that involves `FP-Growth` and I have no idea how to implement it. Is the source code of `FP-Growth` used in `WEKA` available anywhere so i can study the working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weka is indeed Open Source Software (OSS), and their source code is freely available via SVN hosted by the University of Weikato:  http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/svn.html

To find a specific implementation, I would search the Weka Java Docs on SourceForge to identify the class:  http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/.  (Here is [FP-Growth](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/associations/FPGrowth.html)).  Note the class hierarchy beneath the class name:

---

[image: Weka Class Hierarchy]

---

Take that class hierarchy and locate it in SVN by traversing the package names in the version that you want:

---

### [image: Weka SVN Hierarchy]

Click on the link in SVN to open or download the source code.  Here is the link for FP-Growth:  https://svn.cms.waikato.ac.nz/svn/weka/tags/weka-stable-3.6.13/src/main/java/weka/associations/FPGrowth.java (for Weka 3.6.13).

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the version of **FP-Growth** implemented in the [**SPMF data mining library**](http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/) (I'm the founder), which is specialized in pattern mining and offers FPGrowth, and many other algorithms. It is implemented in Java, and it is very easy to reuse it, it is optimized, and unlike some other implementations it has no dependencies to other libraries.